# What are the advantages of using RE Framework in UiPath (Robotic Enterprise Framework)?

Tags: uipath, rpa

I have read many articles that suggest it's better to create an automation project based on the RE framework, rather than creating an empty project and building everything from scratch. Can anybody list the advantages of using this framework? Are there any other frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

the reasons why you should use REFramework:

1.Scalability: The REFramework is designed to handle large-scale automation projects. It supports the development of modular and reusable automation components, which can be easily scaled up or down to meet changing business requirements.

2.Reliability: The REFramework provides a robust and reliable framework for building automations. It includes error handling and recovery mechanisms that help ensure that automations continue to run smoothly even in the face of unexpected errors or failures.

3.Maintainability: The REFramework is designed to be highly maintainable. that make it easy for other developers to understand and modify the code.

4.Customization: The REFramework is highly customizable, and can be easily adapted to meet the specific needs of different automation projects.

5.Reusability: The REFramework supports the development of reusable automation components, which can be easily reused across different automation projects.

Answer (score 1):

I may be in the minority here, but I think that REFramework is way too bulky and bloated to be useful. There is only one case that REFramework is the ideal framework to use and that is if you will be using Queues in Orchestrator. If you will not be using Queues, then in order to not have wasted and irrelevant code, most of the pre-existing functionality of REFramework will need to be deleted.

There are other frameworks available in the UiPath marketplace, but I think the best solution you can have is to create your own library of custom templates.

Because RPA can be hyper-specific to any user's or company's exact needs, there isn't really a good one-size-fits-all for an RPA solution. Creating and saving custom templates is one of the best tools available in UiPath and will allow you to repeatedly create solutions that are specific to your needs. And when they are stored as libraries, you can keep all of your solutions that utilize the templates up to date with a single click.

Let's keep REFramework where it belongs - exclusively in the training modules for UiPath Advanced Certification.